# Can two different functions use the same input variables?

Tags: c, function

If I have int function1(int n), and the input variable in this case is n, can I have another function int function2(int n)? Or would the fact that the two functions have the same input variables somehow interfere with each other.

Comment: They're local to each function, unrelated to each other and not going to cause any problems.  And many, many functions have common names and types for their arguments — it is a non-issue.

Comment: Yes, it's ok, every variable has a scope. The scope of a function parameter is that function. So the two `int n` variables are limited to their respective functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting two comments to a CW answer — so the question can be given closure.*</sup>

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381280/can-two-different-functions-use-the-same-input-variables-in-c#comment54556322_33381280):

> They're local to each function, unrelated to each other and not going to cause any problems. And many, many functions have common names and types for their arguments — it is a non-issue.

And [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) [agreed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381280/can-two-different-functions-use-the-same-input-variables-in-c#comment54556327_33381280):

> Yes, it's ok, every variable has a scope. The scope of a function parameter is that function. So the two `int n` variables are limited to their respective functions.